# Can you ignore columns using dygraphs?

Tags: csv, dygraphs

I basically have a large CSV file with 18 columns in it, but I don't need all that data for my chart.  I just need 4 (the date, and three data values) and ignore the rest.  Does dygraphs let me do this?  Or do I need to find a different library?

I would rather not reparse the CSV file into smaller chunks because I would end up having to manage 20 different CSV files instead of just 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just load all of the values, then hide the data you don't want to see using the visibility option.
http://dygraphs.com/options.html#visibility

> visibility
> Which series should initially be visible? Once the Dygraph has been constructed, you can access and modify the visibility of each series using the visibility and setVisibility methods.
>
> Type: Array of booleans
> Default: [true, true, ...]